# 'Strikes{}/10' prints infinitely

Tags: python

Strikes loops infinitely, and I can't fix it. New to Python so forgive any rookie mistakes. Not fully understanding the syntax yet but I've only been at it for three days. I assume it's because of indentation but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance!

```
    import random



    words = [ 
      'burger',
      'fettucine',
      'lasanga',
      'steak',
      'garlic bread'
      'watermelon',
      'tea',
      'pineapple'
      'coffee',
      'shrimp penne'
    ]

    while True:
      start = input("Press enter to start, or press Q to quit.")
      if start.lower() == 'q':
        break

      secret_word = random.choice(words)
      bad_guesses = []
      good_guesses = []

      while len(bad_guesses) < 10 and len(good_guesses) != len(list(secret_word)):
        for letter in secret_word:
          if letter in good_guesses:
            print(letter, end='')
          else:
              print('_', end='')

        print('')
        print('Strikes: {}/10'.format(len(bad_guesses))) # this is what loops
        print('')


      guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
      if len(guess) != 1:
        print("You can only guess one letter!")

continue 
elif guess in bad_guesses or guess in good_guesses: 
print("You have already guessed that letter.") 
continue 
elif not guess.isalpha(): 
print("You can only guess letters.") continue

if guess in secret_word: 
good_guesses.append(guess) if len(good_guesses) == len(list(secret_word)): print("You win! The word was {}.".format(secret_word)) 

break

else: bad_guesses.append(guess)

else: print("You didn't get it. The word was{}.".format(secret_word))
```

Comment: Fix your indentation! It loops because it is inside the `while len(bad_guesses)` clause.

Comment: Nothing in the while loop (`while len(bad_guesses) < 10 and len(good_guesses) != len(list(secret_word))`) changes, so that loop will just continue indefinitely. You probably meant to have the `guess = ...` lines also inside the loop (and then to do something like update `good_guesses` and `bad_guesses`).

Comment: Oh, I just saw that there's more code that wasn't formatted properly in the question. Maybe that code also belongs in the `while` loop? First fix up the formatting of your question. Just copy/paste your actual code, and then highlight it and click the "{}" button to format it as code. This will preserve all your indentation as you have it.

Comment: Alright, I'll fix it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed code below.

I found a few issues:

1. Some indentation and newlines seem to have been lost when you shared the code.
2. You can't guess spaces, so it's impossible to solve the puzzles that contain spaces ("garlic bread" and "shrimp penne").
3. There were missing commas after `'garlic bread'` and `'pineapple'`.
4. The code that asks for a new guess needs to be inside the inner while loop.
5. There was an `else` with no `if`... I got rid of the `else` and put that code outside the `while` loop. Now the game seems to work fine.

Full fixed code here:

```
import random

words = [ 
    'burger',
    'fettucine',
    'lasanga',
    'steak',
    # commented out since you can't guess spaces
    # 'garlic bread',
    'watermelon',
    'tea',
    'pineapple',
    'coffee',
    # commented out since you can't guess spaces
    # 'shrimp penne',
]

while True:
    start = input("Press enter to start, or press Q to quit.")
    if start.lower() == 'q':
        break

    secret_word = random.choice(words)
    bad_guesses = []
    good_guesses = []

    while len(bad_guesses) < 10 and len(good_guesses) != len(list(secret_word)):
        for letter in secret_word:
            if letter in good_guesses:
                print(letter, end='')
            else:
                    print('_', end='')

        print('')
        print('Strikes: {}/10'.format(len(bad_guesses))) # this is what loops
        print('')

        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print("You can only guess one letter!")
            continue
        elif guess in bad_guesses or guess in good_guesses:
            print("You have already guessed that letter.")
            continue
        elif not guess.isalpha():
            print("You can only guess letters.")
            continue

        if guess in secret_word:
            good_guesses.append(guess)
            if len(good_guesses) == len(list(secret_word)):
                print("You win! The word was {}.".format(secret_word))
                break
        else:
            bad_guesses.append(guess)

    print("You didn't get it. The word was {}.".format(secret_word))
```